# Ember-Rails "Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, precompile, ember-rails

I'm using Ember-Rails to build an Ember front-end app with a Rails API for a beckend. I've been working on implementing authentication, and I arrived at the following error:
`Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined` when trying to extend a route as follows:

```
App.AdminRoute = App.AuthenticateRoute.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('user', params.id);
    },
});
```

And I had an AuthenticateRoute defined as follows:

```
App.AuthenticateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    //yada yada
});
```

I was more-or-less following a guide found on: http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2

I am not sure why this is not working, but I noticed my AuthenticateRoute *could* be extended from other routes, which I find extremely strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that, as most of us know, Ember-Rails precompiles all these files without you seeing it (using what I believe is the Barber gem). What I *didn't* think about is that, when it combines all these files, it (as far as I can tell) puts them in alphabetical order. As such, my `AdminRoute` was being declared as extending `AuthenticateRoute` before `AuthenticateRoute` was even declared, thus producing the error. I'm not yet sure how to solve this--

- A naive fix is to simply change the filename from `admin_route.js` to `zadmin_route.js`, so it comes after `authenticate_route.js`, though this isn't desirable for obvious reasons.
- Alternatively, it is also possible to turn precompiling in Ember-Rails off by setting a flag off. (see [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails#configuration-options))

If anyone has a superior alternative, please comment below, else I will update this when I come across a solution.